# Can you parameterize a template tag library on template directory?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I'm writing a form template tag library for Django, but want to be able to render both Bootstrap and UIKit forms.

The Python code will be identical, except for the template reference. Simplified

```
@register.inclusion_tag('myforms/bootstrap/formrow.html')
def form_row(fieldname, labelpos, labelsize, widgetsize):
    return {...}
```

vs.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('myforms/uikit/formrow.html')
def form_row(fieldname, labelpos, labelsize, widgetsize):
    return {...}
```

I would like to prevent the duplication of the python code, but the `@register.inclusion_tag(..)` function runs very early in the Django lifecycle, so I'm not sure if it is possible, or how to do it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.inclusion_tag) it's possible to register the inclusion tag using a `django.template.Template` instance, which means that you can do the following,

```
# Pseudo code
from django.template.loader import get_template

bootstrap = get_template('myforms/bootstrap/formrow.html')
uikit = get_template('myforms/uikit/formrow.html')

register.inclusion_tag(bootstrap)(re_usable_form_row_function)
register.inclusion_tag(uikit)(re_usable_form_row_function)
```

Comment: I guess I'll need two different files for the register part to prevent a name collision in the `template.Libary()`, but that looks like a nice solution :-)